# SAP BO to Power BI migration

Tags: powerbi, dataset, business-objects, measure, webi

I am migrating SAP BOBJ Webi reports to Power BI. We have loaded the datasets from Oracle DB by running the queries in Power BI Desktop.

While we look at the data view we are not getting custom objects/ measures which the SAP BO report contains due to which creating visualizations is not possible as the visualizations contains custom variables and custom measures.